# Storing/Retrieving Pointer to std::wstring in char Array

Tags: char, byte, c++builder

I am trying to learn more about C++ memory management and type casting. How can I store and retrieve a std::wstring* in a char array? Code or suggestions about what to read would be appreciated.

Here is what I have tried so far. My definition of "Works" is that the correct string appears in the GUI control. "Does not work" means it compiles and runs but gives me a blank in the GUI control.

I'm really curious about why "Wrapper 2" works but not "Wrapper 1".

Integer example (Works):

```
int* lInt(new int);
*lInt = 1500000;
char lBuffer[sizeof(void*)];
memcpy(lBuffer, lInt, sizeof(void*));
int* lInt2 = (int*)lBuffer;
Memo->Lines->Append(IntToStr(*lInt2)); //C++Builder GUI control 
delete lInt;
```

std::wstring Example (Does not work):

```
std::wstring* lMyString = new std::wstring();
*lMyString = L"My Name";
char lBuffer[sizeof(void*)];
memcpy(lBuffer, lMyString, sizeof(void*));
std::wstring* lMyString2 = (std::wstring*)lBuffer;
Memo->Lines->Append(lMyString2->c_str());  //C++Builder GUI control 
delete lMyString;
```

Wrapper 1 (Does not work):

```
struct MyString
{
    std::wstring Text;
};
MyString* lMyString = new MyString();
lMyString->Text = L"My Name";
char lBuffer[sizeof(void*)];
memcpy(lBuffer, lMyString, sizeof(void*));
MyString* lMyString2 = (MyString*)lBuffer;
Memo->Lines->Append(lMyString2->Text.c_str());  //C++Builder GUI control 
delete lMyString;
```

Wrapper 2 (Works):

```
struct MyString
{
    MyString(): Text(new std::wstring()){};
    ~MyString() {delete Text;};
    std::wstring* Text;
};
MyString* lMyString = new MyString();
*lMyString->Text = L"My Name";
char lBuffer[sizeof(void*)];
memcpy(lBuffer, lMyString, sizeof(void*));
MyString* lMyString2 = (MyString*)lBuffer;
Memo->Lines->Append(lMyString2->Text->c_str());  //C++Builder GUI control 
delete lMyString;
```

Comment: [Ideone Sample](https://ideone.com/Vi1GL9) also, why do you want to store pointer in array of characters instead of `void*`?

Comment: Mainly because I don't fully know what I'm doing yet. : - )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How can I store and retrieve a std::wstring* in a char array?

The better way is to store it in `void*`:

```
std::wstring ws;
void *addr = &ws;
// ...
std::wstring retreived = *static_cast<std::wstring*>(addr);
```

> ***** std::wstring Example (Does not work) *****
>
> ```
> std::wstring* lMyString = new std::wstring();
> // ...
> char lBuffer[sizeof(void*)];
> memcpy(lBuffer, lMyString, sizeof(void*));
> std::wstring* lMyString2 = (std::wstring*)lBuffer;
> // ...
> ```

`memcpy` used this way actually copies bytes of the stored std::wstring.

> ```
> void* memcpy( void* dest, const void* src, std::size_t count );
> ```

`lMyString` is a pointer to allocated `std::wstring` and `memcpy` copies bytes from memory `src` points to. What you actually wanted to do is to copy the pointer itself so you need to take address of the pointer:

```
memcpy(lBuffer, &lMyString, sizeof(void*));
```

> ```
>  std::wstring* lMyString2 = (std::wstring*)lBuffer;
> ```

This is also wrong. You are converting address of the first character in `char[]`, not the actual bytes that you stored in the char array before. You should `memcpy` it back:

```
std::wstring* lMyString2 = nullptr;
std::memcpy(&lMyString2, lBuffer, sizeof(void*));
```

As I said, use `void*` instead.

Comment: Thank you razzorflame. I understand better. I made the changes you suggested and now it works.